# Why my Adapter's List LiveData got notified for 3 times when My Fragment is recreated

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

As in below code snippet, I am using list.addAll() in my adapter, when my list is being added 3 times when revisit the fragment again instead of 1 time. However, this does not happen when the fragment is newly created.

Why I got notify 3 times in my scenario from the LiveData? Is it some notify mechanism in LiveData?

Code snippet:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

   public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        model.getMyList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), list -> {
                   adapter.setItemList(list);

            }
        );
    }

}

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public  void    setItemList(List<Item> myList){
        itemList.addAll(myList);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour of LiveData,
While observable being attached to LiveData instance. It is being triggered with the latest value that LiveData has.

To avoid this, you have to create one wrapper class which can validate the data and return null if it was already being handled.

Below solution is derived from google samples.

```
/**
 * Used as a wrapper for data that is exposed via a LiveData that represents an event.
 */
public class Event<T> {

    private T mContent;

    private boolean hasBeenHandled = false;


    public Event( T content) {
        if (content == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("null values in Event are not allowed.");
        }
        mContent = content;
    }
    
    @Nullable
    public T getContentIfNotHandled() {
        if (hasBeenHandled) {
            return null;
        } else {
            hasBeenHandled = true;
            return mContent;
        }
    }
    
    public boolean hasBeenHandled() {
        return hasBeenHandled;
    }
}
```

Now in your viewmodel, assign value to your liveData object by wrapping it inside `Event` class.

```
{yourlist-livedata}.setValue(new Event<List<Item>>({newData}))
```

And in your observable, check it like this,

```
    model.getMyList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), data -> {
               if(data!= null) {
                   val list = data.getContentIfNotHandled()
                   if(list!= null){
                       adapter.setItemList(list);
                   }
               }
        }
    );
```

Following above approach you won't get duplicate data issue.